# using std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator; (Console App works, VCL App Doesn't)

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm wanting to use `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` to list files in a folder and subfolder.

This code works fine in a Console Application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using std::cout; using std::cin;
using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator;

int main() {
    string path = "./";

    for (const auto & file : recursive_directory_iterator(path))
        cout << file.path() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, in the VCL App with the following code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using std::cout; using std::cin;
using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator;

#include "OSSEncryptByList.h"
#include "OSSMain.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TEncryptByListForm *EncryptByListForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TEncryptByListForm::TEncryptByListForm(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
} 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TEncryptByListForm::ShowListForm()
{
    // blah...
```

The error message is:

> [bcc32 Error] OSSEncryptByList.cpp(11): E2209 Unable to open include file 'filesystem'

For some reason, `#include <filesystem>` is failing in the VCL Application but not in the Console Application.

Comment: `<filesystem>` is quite a recent addition to C++ (version C++17 I think), so my bet would be the two compilers are supporting different versions of C++.

Comment: The question doesn't have to do with `recursive_directory_iterator` at all but rather the lack of `<filesystem>`. Are you using the old compiler or the new clang-enhanced compiler?

Comment: Sidenote: `#include <fstream.h>` ... no, it's `#include <fstream>`

Comment: Fwiw: I just made a VCL app in _C++Builder 10.4 Community Edition_ and compiled it with both the classic and the clang-enhanced compiler. Both found `<filesystem>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the "classic" Borland 32-bit compiler does not support C++11 or later versions, though it does have [a few C++11 features](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B11_Features_in_the_Classic_Compiler), but `<filesystem>` is not one of them. Did you compile for 64-bit instead? The 64-bit compiler is a clang compiler and [does support `<filesystem>`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Modern_C%2B%2B_Language_Features_Compliance_Status)

Comment: @RemyLebeau True that. I just wanted to point out that both compilers _found_ the header, which seems to be the problem OP is struggling with right now. I suspect something's wrong with the installation or project setup. No, I compiled for 32-bit in both cases.

Comment: @TedLyngmo unless you actually used the newer clang 32bit compiler and not the classic 32bit compiler, then I see no possible way the classic compiler could work with `<filesystem>`. Even if it found the header, the header uses C++11 features that the classic compiler simply doesn't implement.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm a bit confused myself. I opened it up again, fresh VCL project. "All configurations - Windows 32-bit platform" / "C++ Compilers (WIN32)" / Use 'classic' Borland complier ☑ ... erhm... and `auto a = recursive_directory_iterator(".");` and range based for-loops works. wtf..? :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Found it - It's a bug in the IDE. _"All configurations - Windows 32-bit platform"_ apparently doesn't mean **all** configurations, even if I unchecked and re-checked the _"Use 'classic' Borland complier"_ checkbox. When looking at my Debug config, the box was unchecked. Checking it explicitly for the Debug configuration made the compilation fail as expected :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*"All configurations ..." apparently doesn't mean **all** configurations*" - it does, UNLESS you have a more specific configuration present, then that takes priority. Settings aren't inherited the way you would expect. It is not really a bug, it is just a really awkward design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Console project is configured to use a [Clang-based C++ compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers), but your GUI project is configured to use the ["classic" Borland C++ compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32) instead.  The classic compiler does not support C++11, and thus cannot use the `<filesystem>` library.  You will have to go into your Project Options and disable the `"Use 'classic' Borland compiler"` option in the [C++ Compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler) settings.

Comment: Many Thanks, Remy and others who identified the same. However changing the compiler is throwing up a bunch of new errors, which I am trying to address. One which I have not yet been able to address is that of a FASTREPORT .hpp file which is supposed to be included, which is now throwing up an error, of not being able to fine. [bcc32c Fatal Error] OSSGzXYGraph.h(17): 'frxClass.hpp' file not found

Comment: The app in question is 20 yrs old, with regular updates and extensions of features since. The latest is a requirement that all the data files it runs off, be encrypted. It has some 62 units and forms. I'm leaning towards trying to find another way to list files within a folder, than deal with all the errors the new compiler throws up. I guess that is a question for another post.

Comment: To enumerate files, the RTL has `FindFirst()`, `FindNext()`, and `FindClose()` functions in the `System.SysUtils.hpp` header, and a static `TDirectory.GetFiles()` method in the `System.IOUtils.hpp` header